# swift app crashes when dismissing view after selecting photo from UIImagePickerView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to open UIImagePickerView Controller From Collection View in SWIFT. When I select the photo and dismiss the photo library, the app crashes. This is the code that I have. Does anyone have an idea? I have the same code in Objective C, and it works completely.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class selectPhotos:UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UIActionSheetDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate{

var processingProduct:ProcessingProduct!
var uploadedImages:NSMutableArray = []

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var img:UIImage = UIImage(named: "addPhoto.png")
    uploadedImages = [img]
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var img:UIImage = UIImage(named: "addPhoto.png")
    uploadedImages = [img]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return uploadedImages.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("photoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as photoCell
    cell.productPhoto.image = (uploadedImages[indexPath.row] as UIImage)
    cell.productPhoto.tag = indexPath.row

    let tapOnPhoto: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapOnPhoto:")
    tapOnPhoto.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.productPhoto.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.deletePhoto.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.productPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnPhoto)
    var count = self.uploadedImages.count - 1

    if indexPath.row != count{
        cell.deletePhoto.hidden = false
    }else{
        cell.deletePhoto.hidden = true
    }
    cell.deletePhoto.targetForAction("deletePhoto:", withSender: self)

    return cell
}

func tapOnPhoto(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){

    var tableGridImage:UIImageView = gestureRecognizer.view as UIImageView
    var index:Int = tableGridImage.tag
    var count = self.uploadedImages.count - 1
    if index == count {
        uploadItemPhotos()
    }
}

//MARK: - Implement Upload Photo Actions

func uploadItemPhotos(){

    var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet();
    sheet.delegate = self;
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel");
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Take a photo");
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Pick from library");
    sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0;
    sheet.showInView(self.view);

}

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

    if buttonIndex == 1{

        var available = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)
        println(available)

        if available == true{

            var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePickerController.delegate = self
                imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
                imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
                self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            println("Camera is not available on this devicce")
        }

    }

    if buttonIndex == 2{

        var available = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum)
        println(available)

        if available == true{
            var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePickerController.delegate = self
                imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
                imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
                self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: { imageP in
            })
        }else{
            println("Photo libarary is not available on this device")
        }
   }
}


//MARK: - Getting Image Info

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    var count = self.uploadedImages.count - 1
    var addedImage:UIImage = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    self.uploadedImages.insertObject(addedImage, atIndex: count)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

func deletePhoto(sender:UIButton){
    self.uploadedImages.removeObjectAtIndex(sender.tag)
}
}
```

Comment: Did you check out the crash log in your phone?

Comment: I am testing it on simulator.

Comment: Please update your question with exception of crash log you are having. Only than we can sort out problem.